# Dropdown Menus - with UL and LI HTML, CSS, JS | Mobile Issue

Tags: html, css

I installed dropdown menu's (using UL and LI HTML codes) on my website and users are having problem on their mobile devices. Here's an [example](http://www.newlay.caedon.net/index.html) of what it looks like on my site, it completely ruins the way the layout is supposed to look. Is there any way to keep my dropdown menus while still working decently on Mobile devices?

I'm a little past novice skill, I've been web designing casually for the past 11 years.. I know a thing or two but don't assume much.

Comment: if you refer to the hover effect, as for your current menu, mobile devices won't have the hover effect, most touch screen recognize touch = click.

Comment: @Math3w So, theoretically, remove the fancy hover effect and it should work for mobile devices?

Comment: of course you will need css and jquery to make them work. eg. hide the second level menu, and use jquery to make them shows when the 1st level menu is clicked.